# How do I stop my EBB (Eccentric Bottom Bracket) from creaking?

Tags: maintenance, bottom-bracket, noise, creak

I have a '09 Felt Niner 29" SS with an EBB. After a thorough clean and reassembly of the BB the creaking will subside for a ride or so and then come back. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** the problem appears to be dirt getting into the bottom bracket area. The combination of sweat, water bottle drip'age or post ride spray down results in dirt getting into the BB area. The only way I can see to prevent the creaking is to somehow seal off the exposed face of the BB preventing dirt from getting inside.

Comment: Click and Clack solution: Turn up the radio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular EBB has two set screws which press into the EBB cups and prevent them from rotating. Due to the gear ratio that I'm running and the pressure I'm applying my EBB is slightly rotating which then causes the screws to scrape metal off part of the EBB cups. The resulting metal fragments find their way into the EBB chamber and are what result in the creaking.

The fix as someone jokingly made once was to get a new frame and ditch the EBB. I think I've come around to their way of thinking. As it is now I have to remove and clean the EBB once every 1-2 weeks.

BTW I tried all the other alternatives with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Your mileage may vary, but this has worked for me.  Try using some telfon tape around the outside of the EBB before you put it in.  It's cheap and you can get it at a local hardware store in the plumbing section.

Comment: I tried this but the fit is so tight that the tape gets shoved off when I try to insert the BB.

Answer (score 2):

Try greasing the interface between parts. The bolts provide enough clamping power to prevent slippage.  Also confirm the creaking is indeed coming from the EBB.

Comment: From what I've read, adding a bit of lube to the bolts is actually recommended.  Though lubing the interface between almost any component isn't a horrible idea on a bicycle.

Comment: I've had issues with my EBB creaking that have been fixed with a gentle application of grease to all the mating surfaces, didn't worry too much about the bolts.  Do also make sure it's not your cranks or chainring bolts or other, creaky, parts.

Comment: It's definitely the EBB. I did a clean and complete grease the first time and the creaking came back. It's possible that the BB cup is getting warped due to running a low gear ratio. Going to try the tape and see if that fills the gaps.